# SlaarToolkit - Only 32 Bit ARGB pixel format is supported, not Format32bppArgb

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to convert Format32bppArgb to 32 bit argb and how?

EDIT: Ok, I'am loading a default `SlaarToolkit` marker:

```
var marker = Marker.LoadFromResource("/Content/Marker_SLAR_16x16segments_80width.pat", 16, 16, 80);
```

and when i run the app i am getting InvalidOperationException with message:

```
Only 32 Bit ARGB pixel format is supported, not Format32bppArgb
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It sounds like you're saying "I need X but all I have is X," so it's hard to see the problem.

Comment: Are you using a precompiled version of that toolkit or are you using the source code of it?  If you use the source, you can set a breakpoint to investigate the types that are being passed around.

Comment: i am using as it comes out off the box...

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like something wrong with either that library, the content file you are trying to load, or the Windows Phone CLR itself.

Here is the code from the library that is throwing that exception:

```
/// <summary>
/// Invoked when a video device reports a  video format change.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="videoFormat">The new video format.</param>
protected override void OnFormatChange(VideoFormat videoFormat)
{
    if (videoFormat.PixelFormat != PixelFormatType.Format32bppArgb)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Only 32 Bit ARGB pixel format is supported, not {0}.", videoFormat.PixelFormat));
    }

    detector.ChangeFormat(videoFormat.PixelWidth, videoFormat.PixelHeight);
    vidFormat = videoFormat;
}
```

That's a pretty straightforward comparison and would lead me to believe that the videoFormat parameter's PixelFormat property is not actually PixelFormatType.Format32bppArgb.

Without a lot more detail and a much larger code sample, as well as the file that is causing the problem, it's pretty much impossible to tell what's going on here.

I really can't imagine how this could happen, since both VideoFormat and PixelFormatType are built-in CLR types for Windows Phone.  PixelFormatType is a simple enum and isn't even bit-flagged, so it can't be an issue with overlapping bit fields.  VideoFormat's PixelFormat property is of type PixelFormatType, so it shouldn't be possible for you to be throwing this exception with this value.

I would report this to both the developer of the library and Microsoft, as this seems like something is going very wrong in an invisible way.

Does this happen when you try it with other content files?

Comment: yes, with any other custom made markers. however i do not know how to solve that because i cannot edit the `.pat`

Comment: That would still indicate an issue in the CLR or the library, as that shouldn't be where the exception occurs and it certainly shouldn't be THAT exception.  Report it to the developer of the SLAR toolkit and provide your sample file.  You've discovered a bug and it isn't your own code that's causing it (I don't think).